# Do MySQL indexes automatically take in account ORDER BY?

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

If I create a index on (name, created_at) and I

```
SELECT * WHERE name='blah' and created_at="blah" ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

Would that index take care of "order by"?

If not, how would I create the index so ORDER BY is more efficient?

Comment: What do you mean, "would the index take care of order by?"

Answer (score 0):

Where possible, indexes are used for ordering. In your example, however, since all results will have the value of "blah" for created_at, there's nothing to order. Did you mean the following?

```
SELECT * WHERE name='blah' ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

In the above case, the compound "covering" index (name, created_at) would be used for both the `WHERE` selection and the sorting.

The default index type is a btree, and the top of the tree would have all the values for `name` ordered. Below each name branch, each `created_at` would be ordered.

So, MySQL would utilize the top of the index to locate the section of the index where `name` equals 'blah', and use the rest of the branches below that to return the primary keys for the `created_at` results, in the same order as the index.

Since the records would be returned, already in order, there would be no need to further sort them.

Comment: So in your example, I need to create a compound index (name, created_at), right? If I just index name, then query is not optimized for sorting. Correc?

Comment: This is somewhat dependent on the version of MySQL. Later versions of MySQL may be able to utilize a separate index for ordering. However, if you have a compound index with (name, created_at), it will work in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

The BTREE indexes (default) can be used to sort. If an indexwill be used depends on what the optimizer figures out.

You can use EXPLAIN in front of your query to see this.

For this query, the ORDER BY will not have much impact as you look for a specific created_at.

If your query was more like this:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE name='blah' ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

or even

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE name='blah' and created_at BETWEEN 'a' AND 'z' ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

You would get better results using a single index on both name and created_at (in that order). It would first use the index to match the name and then use the same index to sort the results.

```
ALTER TABLE foo ADD INDEX (`name`, `created_at`)
```

Of course, this still needs to be validated with EXPLAIN. The database optimizer will do what it thinks is best depending on the exact query values and the amount of data it estimates.